# When should I use Unclump button on the Align and Distribute tab?

Tags: inkscape

I don't know what the **Unclump** button on the Align and Distribute tab does. After experimenting, it seems to just move objects around. Can someone can explain to me what it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unclump tries to move objects (as little as possible) to remove overlappings and irregular distances between objects.

Select *multiple* objects and click unclump, possibly multiple times.

The following image shows the results of selecting the colored disks and unclumping them 1 and 10 times.

[image: unclumping the colored disks]

Answer (score 0):

From the [Inkscape release notes](https://inkscape.org/en/release/0.42/) that I found with a simple Google Search:

> The new Unclump button attempts to reduce the *local unevenness* in distribution of the tiles. When you unclump a tiling, each tile tries to move to a point equidistant from its closest neighbors. If a single unclumping is not enough, you can press Unclump repeatedly, trying to achieve a balance between eliminating small-scale clumps and preserving large-scale features of the tiling. Unclumping can be applied to both randomized and regular tilings, changing them both into a characteristic texture which appears random, but not blindly random — very similar to what a human would produce if asked to evenly fill a space with random dots. As a result, properly unclumped dot tilings remind of hand-made engravings.

In short: move objects to more evenly space the edge-to-edge distances, as mentioned in the [Inkscape Manual](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Align.html#Align-Distribute-2D)

Comment: thank for reply my question. But  I still don't understand the condition of _local unevenness_ object and evenly object. Can u give me little example? (maybe with picture if u have time).